# Substitute zeros in array of numbers by numbers in respective positions from another array

Tags: javascript

I have 2 arrays:

```
arr1 = [0,0,3,0,2,1,0];
arr2 = [1,4,0,3,0,0,3];
```

As per the requirement, the resulting array should contain all the element of arr1 and arr2. Only 0s of each array to be replaced by the non zero values of any of these arrays in the same order.

```
result = [1,4,3,3,2,1,3];
```

Is there any way to do that in JavaScript or jQuery? Should I use any data structure key value pair to achieve it. And is there any way to merge more than 2 such arrays?

Comment: and if in the same index both have a value that is not 0, but those 2 values are different? PS: the downvotes are caused by the fact that you have not shown what you have tried so far

Comment: @Berto99 As per the requirement, in the same index, only one of the 2 arrays will have a non zero value

Comment: Can you clarify your requirements please?  Why is `result` not `[1,4,3,3,2,1,3]` -- i.e. why was one of the elements omitted?

Comment: You can zip the data my mapping.

Comment: but shouldn't the end result be then `[1,4,3,3,2,1,3];`?

Comment: @dbc, you are absolutely right. I have omitted an element in the result array by mistake

Answer (score 1):

Simple `Array.prototype.map()` may do the trick:

```js
const arr1 = [0,0,3,0,2,1,0],
      arr2 = [1,4,0,3,0,0,3],
      
      result = arr1.map((n,i) => n || arr2[i])
      
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can zip 2 or more arrays with the following.

You need to map the positions of the first array to a reduction for that position across all the arrays.

While reducing, you keep the current value, unless its zero and you use the previous value.

```js
const zipMask = (...arr) => arr[0].map((__x, innerIndex) =>
  arr.reduce((prev, __a, outerIndex) =>
    arr[outerIndex][innerIndex] || prev, 0));

console.log(zipMask([0,0,3,0,2,1,0], [1,4,0,3,0,0,3]).join(', '));
```

Here is a more verbose version with error checking.

```js
const zipMask = (...arr) => {
  if (arr.length === 0) {
    throw new Error('Please supply teo or more arrays');
  }
  if (arr.length === 1) {
    return arr[0]; // Just go ahead and return first one.
  }
  const first = arr[0];
  if (arr.some(a => a.length !== first.length)) {
    throw new Error('Lengths must be equal');
  }
  return first.map((__x, innerIndex) => {
    return arr.reduce((prev, __a, outerIndex) => {
      return arr[outerIndex][innerIndex] || prev;
    }, 0);
  })
};

console.log(zipMask([0,0,3,0,2,1,0], [1,4,0,3,0,0,3]).join(', '));
```